# C++ Linux Binary terminated with signal SIGKILL - why? (loaded in GDB)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb

So I fire up my c++ application in GDB, and when it quits, I basically get:

```
[Thread 0x7fff76e07700 (LWP 6170) exited]
[Thread 0x7fff76f08700 (LWP 6169) exited]
[Thread 0x7fff77009700 (LWP 6168) exited] 
...
Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed. The program no longer exists.
(gdb)
```

I literally have no idea why this is occuring, why can't I do a backtrace to see how it exited?  Anyone have any ideas?  It should never end :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I literally have no idea why this is occuring,

This usually means that either

- some other process executed a `kill -9 <your-pid>`, or
- the kernel OOM killer decided that your process consumed too many resources, and terminated it (effectively the kernel executed `kill -9` for it). You should look in `/var/log/messages` (`/var/log/syslog` on Ubuntu variants) for traces of that -- the kernel usually logs a message when it OOMs some process.

> why can't I do a backtrace to see how it exited?

Because in order to see a backtrace, the process must exist. If it doesn't exist, it doesn't have stack, and so *can't* have backtrace.

Comment: Or the programmer wanted to be clever for some reason and one of the threads is killing its own program with SIGKILL.

Comment: Would there be another log I should be checking (I'm on ubuntu)?

Comment: @Geesu : check /var/log/syslog

Comment: Also ``strace`` can help you to find attempt of access to inaccessible or restricted OS resource and find the cause of ``sigkill``.

Comment: in my case, it was a out of memory, the system seemed to kill it: [417558.146474] Out of memory: Kill process 20867 (xxxx) score 42 or sacrifice child
[417558.147973] Killed process 20867 (xxxx) total-vm:362268kB, anon-rss:271668kB, file-rss:2728kB, shmem-rss:0kB https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/out-of-memory-kill-process-or-sacrifice-child

Comment: @BillYan That's the kernel OOM killer mentioned as one of the possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Unix/Linux you should also be able to type `dmesg` on your terminal and see the cause of the process terminating. In my case it was indeed OOM. [here is a screenshot of my kernel log shortly after the termination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RFwF.png)

Comment: *dmesg* the way to go

Comment: Yes, dmesg worked and tell you the reason why it happend. In my case, it shows

[5087530.276277] Out of memory: Kill process 19056...

[5087530.276324] Killed process 19056 ...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the process ran into the cpu time ulimit. Check with **ulimit -a** from the environment where the process is actually started if "cpu time" is set to anything other than "unlimited"

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a segmentation fault? Isn't that a buffer overflow?

Comment: @yash101 why would it cause segfault? Segmentation fault is when one access a memory in a way that is not allowed. It have nothing to do with CPU time.

Comment: When did I make that comment and why? It makes no sense! I feel like something changed!

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a crash (AV). Even with GDB attached I couldn't catch this violation.
Hope it helps